# Drive fault was asserted DELL

Tags: raid, hp, dell, hp-proliant, dell-poweredge

i have a DELL PowerEdge 2950 Server whit raid for 3 HDD.
A friend whit a HP Proliant server which has broken, come to my help, to save information from the hard drive only had. When i put on my server his not reconized, and the error it's: HDD4 drive fault was deasserted and after HDD4 drive fault was asserted
The HDD is HP to.
Sorry for my bad english my language is Spanish!!

Comment: If it's so urgent, you should probably look for a professional instead of relying on advice from strangers on the internet.  You could also just rebuild the raid from scratch and restore from backups.  You do have backups don't you?

Comment: So you took a dead hard drive from an HP server and put it in a Dell Server?

Comment: Your friend should replace the defective drive and then restore his backups.

Comment: thanks for answer me so fast, my raid is not scratch, my questions is about my friend hdd is not recognized on my server! whit the message i described below

Comment: @joeqwerty yes it´s the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to read an HP Smart Array-formatted disk in a Dell's (LSI) controller. Ideally, your friend will need to use another HP server in order to read the data contained on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You generally cannot move disks that were in a hardware RAID between different controllers and reconstruct the array. In this case, Dell PERCs and HP P-series RAID controllers are very different. You should be moving the RAID controller *along* with the disks if you want this to work.